# pandas.DataFrame.head doesn't work in MS Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have just installed MS Visual Studio Code to use python having used Jupyter Notebooks for learning for the last couple of years. I tried to use a standard piece of Pandas and it won't do anything

```
import pandas as pd
url = "C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/train.csv"
train=pd.read_csv(url)

train.head(2)
```

The terminal just prints this:

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX> & C:/Users/XXXX/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe "c:/Users/XXXX/Documents/Python Scripts/import house price.py"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not the output of the program, make sure you install python extension for vs code that you can run and debug your python scripts with. In this case, everything seems to be normal, hit enter in the terminal and it should run your script.

Comment: I have the  Python, Pylance, Jupyter, Jupyter Keymap and Jupyter Notebook Renderers extensions installed.

I added "Python for VSCode" but I get the following error on the Runtime Status page "'configuration.jsonValidation.url' must be an absolute URL or start with './' to reference schemas located in the extension."

Comment: Looks like the "Python for VSCode" wont help, apparently out of date.

Comment: I think you need to hit ctrl + c on your vscode terminal and try again. You can also completely close the terminal with the trash can symbol near terminal and open a new terminal with + sign.

Comment: That did nothing. Tried both still get no output from pandas head

Comment: because you have to `print` the output of `train.head(2)` with `print(train.head(2))` if you want to see the output in console.

Comment: Thanks. I presume this is a difference between Jupyter Notebooks and MS Visual Studio Code. JN doesn't need the print...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio Code, this problems was because I had selected File / New File / Python File, and didn't work the property dataframe.head()

Solution
For solution this problem in Visual Studio Code I selected File / New File / Jupyter Notebook

[image]

[image]